# Flutter: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task

Tags: package, flutter, yaml

I am trying to run a code , but I have this error, I updated the version of the packages in the yaml file but sill have the same issue. any ideas ?

ps: this code is working on another pc , but the issue is about mine

[image]

Comment: Check these links  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bROui4ID9_Q&feature=youtu.be
 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18579#issuecomment-398484148
    https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19868
    https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19983
    https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20486

Comment: it finally worked Thanksss alottt

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/build.gradle folder and add the next line of code at the very end of the document:

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Then save a run it again